# Programatically Start UWP app after installation

Tags: windows, uwp, store

I am creating a Store Build for my UWP app. I would like the app to run automatically (without user intervention) once installed on end-user device. Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid you can’t let the app run automatically after installation.

Currently, uwp doesn’t provide such api to do this. If you do want this feature, please feel free to submit your feature requirement with Windows Feedback Hub app.